# Firebase function reach timeout while executing a simple operation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a firebase function getting some data from a firebase realtime database. As I have to retrieve data from several nodes, I fill an array of database request promises. Below is the code:

```
exports.function = functions.database.ref('/nodeA/{nodeBId}/nodeC/{nodeDId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    let userKeysSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(`/nodeA/${nodeBId}/nodeE`).once('value'); 
    let userKeys = Object.keys(userKeysSnapshot.val());

    let promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < userKeys .length; i++) {
        console.log("Before push"); // printed in firebase journal
        promises.push(admin.database().ref('/users/'+ userKeys [i] + '/node2').once('value'));    // <= execution seems to be blocked here
        console.log("After push");  // never printed in firebase journal
    }

    let snapshots = await Promise.all(getDeviceTokensPromises);

    ...
});
```

I added some console log around the push operation and the result is I get only the first log at the first iteration of the loop. Furthermore, in the firebase function journal I can see the function reach timeout.

Firebase journal:

```
4:56:43.818 PM functionName   Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
4:55:44.524 PM functionName   Before push
```

Do you have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: The code you shared shows no usage of Google Cloud Functions, so it's impossible to be certain how it causes the time-out (although I suspect you're not returning a promise). Please provide a [minimal, **complete**, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: I have updated the example, actually this function is a Firebase Function.